# Is there any VS Code extension that compile code in workspace and show that which line takes how much time to execute?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone knows that is there any extension that is compile code in VS code workspace and show developer that which line will take how much time to execute and which line is invalid or buggy..

If it is available then please mention here.

Comment: They are used to be called `Reviewers` and also helpful are the `Coding colleagues`. Do a search for `profiling` and your used language

Comment: Thanks for reply. let me do research about it.